# How can I make my Sqlreader reads a record when the record has only one row?

Tags: sql, vb.net

Below I have a program that reads content of a table and does some formatting on them before writing it out. I have 2 arrays temp and values, because some columns in the table has too long description that jumps to the next line ID it reaches a maximum character of 80.

Here is my Problem, my program works fine when there are more than one record in the database. But when there is just one record it escapes to the catch. Please, someone help me on why this doesn't work when there is only one record in the Database Table.

```
Try
    Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter(filepath, False)
        Dim values(SQLReader.FieldCount) As Object
        Dim temp(SQLReader.FieldCount) As Object
        Dim first As Boolean = True


        While SQLReader.Read()
            'Dim values(SQLReader.FieldCount) As Object
            SQLReader.GetValues(values)

            If values(12) IsNot DBNull.Value Then
                values(12) = Convert.ToDateTime(values(12)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff")
                values(15) = Convert.ToDateTime(values(15)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff")
            End If

            values(1) = Convert.ToDateTime(values(1)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff")
            values(8) = Convert.ToDateTime(values(8)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff")
            values(13) = values(13).ToString.Replace(",", " ")
            values(13) = values(13).ToString.Replace(vbLf, " ")

            If first Then
                values.CopyTo(temp, 0)
                SQLReader.Read()
                SQLReader.GetValues(values)
                If values(12) IsNot DBNull.Value Then
                    values(12) = Convert.ToDateTime(values(12)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff")
                    values(15) = Convert.ToDateTime(values(15)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff")
                End If
                values(1) = Convert.ToDateTime(values(1)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff")
                values(8) = Convert.ToDateTime(values(8)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff")
                values(13) = values(13).ToString.Replace(",", " ")
                values(13) = values(13).ToString.Replace(vbLf, " ")
                first = False
            End If

            If values(14) Is DBNull.Value Then
                values(14) = 1
            End If

            If CInt(values(14)) > 1 Then
                temp(13) = temp(13).ToString() & values(13).ToString
            Else

                sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", temp))
                values.CopyTo(temp, 0)
                Repaircounter += 1
            End If
        End While
```

Comment: Firstly, you haven't shown us any `Catch` block. Secondly, that means that an exception has been thrown so that exception, which you haven't told us anything about, will tell what actually happened. It's not there to be ignored.

Comment: BTW, you specify the upper bound, not the length, when you create an array. It seems rather silly to be using all those magic numbers all over the place and then using `SQLReader.FieldCount` to create the arrays, as though you don't know how many fields there are going to be.

Comment: Inside your While loop you do another SQLReader.Read(), within an If first Then statement. If that Read command is reached and there is only one row, an exception will occur.

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson Wilson thank you for pointing me to the right direction